# Resize Album Artwork Form mp3 File

Tags: ios, image, resize, imageview

I have to resize an album artwork form the file I get with this code:

```
for (NSString *format in [asset availableMetadataFormats]) {
        for (AVMetadataItem *item in [asset metadataForFormat:format]) {
            if ([[item commonKey] isEqualToString:@"title"]) {
                //NSLog(@"name: %@", (NSString *)[item value]);
                downloadedCell.nameLabel.text = (NSString *)[item value];

            }
            if ([[item commonKey] isEqualToString:@"artist"]) {
                downloadedCell.artistLabel.text = (NSString *)[item value];
            }
            if ([[item commonKey] isEqualToString:@"albumName"]) {
                //musicItem.strAlbumName = (NSString *)[item value];
            }
            if ([[item commonKey] isEqualToString:@"artwork"]) {
                UIImage *img = nil;
                if ([item.keySpace isEqualToString:AVMetadataKeySpaceiTunes]) {
                    img = [UIImage imageWithData:[item.value copyWithZone:nil]];
                }
                else { // if ([item.keySpace isEqualToString:AVMetadataKeySpaceID3]) {
                    NSData *data = [(NSDictionary *)[item value] objectForKey:@"data"];
                    img = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

                }
                // musicItem.imgArtwork = img;
                UIImage *newImage = [self resizeImage:img width:70.0f height:70.0f];
                downloadedCell.artworkImage.image = newImage;

            }
```

When I apply this method:

```
- (UIImage *)resizeImage:(UIImage *)image width:(int)width height:(int)height {
    //NSLog(@"resizing");
    CGImageRef imageRef = [image CGImage];
    CGImageAlphaInfo alphaInfo = CGImageGetAlphaInfo(imageRef);

    //if (alphaInfo == kCGImageAlphaNone)
    alphaInfo = kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast;

    CGContextRef bitmap = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, width, height, CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(imageRef),
                                                4 * width, CGImageGetColorSpace(imageRef), alphaInfo);
    CGContextDrawImage(bitmap, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), imageRef);
    CGImageRef ref = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmap);
    UIImage *result = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:ref];

    CGContextRelease(bitmap);
    CGImageRelease(ref);

    return result; 
}
```

I ALWAYS get a noise image like you can see in the photo above.
http://postimage.org/image/jltpfza11/

How can I get a better resolution image?

Comment: The "xcode" tag is for questions relating to the IDE itself, not for general iOS programming questions.

Comment: Have you tried passing a larger size to your resize function?

Comment: YES, it resizes it noisy too!

Comment: Try using the unresized image. Is it noisy?

Comment: the uresized image goes out of bounds of the ImageView. Is there a way to prevent it?

Comment: Yes, just set the imageView's contentMode to something like UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill

Comment: I set aspectFill in customCell class but it become like that: http://postimage.org/image/p498owx97/

Comment: - (void)awakeFromNib {
    artworkImage.layer.magnificationFilter = kCAFilterNearest;
    
    [artworkImage setBounds:CGRectMake(9, 9, 74, 74)];
    [artworkImage setFrame:CGRectMake(9, 9, 74, 74)];
    [artworkImage setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill];
}

Comment: You shouldn't set the magnificationFilter of a UIImageView. I would also avoid settings its bounds. Are you sure nothing else is overwriting the content mode later? Try logging it when you set the image. Also, you should confirm that you're setting the image on the main thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your view is 74x74, you should resize to twice that on retina displays. So, something like:

```
CGFloat imageSize = 74.0f * [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
UIImage *newImage = [self resizeImage:img width:imageSize height:imageSize];
```

Then you need to set the contentMode of your image view to something like UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill.

Comment: 74 is the unretina dimension... how can I set aspect fill on a customCell?

Comment: Have you confirmed that you're not overriding the content mode elsewhere. Setting it in awakeFromNib should be fine. Try logging the content mode when you set the image, and confirm that you're setting all these image view properties from the *main thread*.

Answer (score 0):

Try specify explicitly the level of interpolation for the context using:

```
CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(bitmap, kCGInterpolationHigh);
```

Your resizeImage:width:height: method thus becomes:

```
-(UIImage *)resizeImage:(UIImage *)image width:(int)width height:(int)height {
   //NSLog(@"resizing");
   CGImageRef imageRef = [image CGImage];
   CGImageAlphaInfo alphaInfo = CGImageGetAlphaInfo(imageRef);

   //if (alphaInfo == kCGImageAlphaNone)
   alphaInfo = kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast;

   CGContextRef bitmap = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, width, height, CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(imageRef),
                                            4 * width, CGImageGetColorSpace(imageRef), alphaInfo);
   CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(bitmap, kCGInterpolationHigh);
   CGContextDrawImage(bitmap, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), imageRef);
   CGImageRef ref = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmap);
   UIImage *result = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:ref];

   CGContextRelease(bitmap);
   CGImageRelease(ref);

   return result;
```

}